# MySQL GROUP BY incoherence

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having an issue with a query, and more specifically the GROUP BY function.

The query works perfectly and returns the right results in the right order, but when I try to group by user ID, it messes up everything.

```
SELECT u.ID, GREATEST( IF(c.climb_length >= 1, r.cotation_1, 0)
, IF(c.climb_length >= 2, r.cotation_2, 0)
, IF(c.climb_length >= 3, r.cotation_3, 0)
, IF(c.climb_length >= 4, r.cotation_4, 0)
, IF(c.climb_length >= 5, r.cotation_5, 0)
, IF(c.climb_length >= 6, r.cotation_6, 0)
, IF(c.climb_length >= 7, r.cotation_7, 0)
, IF(c.climb_length >= 8, r.cotation_8, 0)
, IF(c.climb_length >= 9, r.cotation_9, 0)
, IF(c.climb_length >= 10, r.cotation_10, 0)
) AS vmax
FROM users u
INNER JOIN climbs c
ON c.user_id = u.ID
INNER JOIN routes r
ON c.route_id = r.ID
GROUP BY vmax, u.ID
ORDER BY vmax DESC
```

This returns something like that, which is close to what I want, except for the duplicate u.IDs (usernames displayed for readability):

[image]

The problem is, I only want the highest vmax per u.ID - each u.ID appearing only once. So if I do the same request but with only `GROUP BY u.ID`, I get this, which makes no sense:

[image]

Here, the vmax values are wrong, hence the order is wrong. I don't even understand where those values come from: the vmax value for each u.ID does not even match the last inserted vmax of each user as calculated by the query (I can show that if I add `c.ID` in the `SELECT` part), nor the first one. They do belong to each user, but they are all over the place chronologically.

I have tried many things, researched and read a lot (for example [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-handling.html) seemed promising), but it doesn't make much sense to me that this last bit above does not work. Does anyone see where I messed up?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the first result correct and as per your expectation? And what exactly is the problem with output?

Comment: Did you try `MAX(GREATEST(...))`?

Comment: @RohitAggarwal The problem with the first result is the duplicate IDs. Each user should appear only once. So the order is fine but I want to get rid of the other results!

Comment: @SalmanA I have tried a million times with MAX, which was completely logical, but for some reason it always returned an error. Must have been a typo. The (now accepted) answer below evidently works...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use aggregate function `MAX` and group by `u.ID` only:

```
SELECT u.ID, MAX(GREATEST( IF(c.climb_length >= 1, r.cotation_1, 0)
, IF(c.climb_length >= 2, r.cotation_2, 0)
, IF(c.climb_length >= 3, r.cotation_3, 0)
, IF(c.climb_length >= 4, r.cotation_4, 0)
, IF(c.climb_length >= 5, r.cotation_5, 0)
, IF(c.climb_length >= 6, r.cotation_6, 0)
, IF(c.climb_length >= 7, r.cotation_7, 0)
, IF(c.climb_length >= 8, r.cotation_8, 0)
, IF(c.climb_length >= 9, r.cotation_9, 0)
, IF(c.climb_length >= 10, r.cotation_10, 0)
)) AS vmax
FROM users u
INNER JOIN climbs c
ON c.user_id = u.ID
INNER JOIN routes r
ON c.route_id = r.ID
GROUP BY u.ID
ORDER BY vmax DESC
```

Comment: I have tried a million times with MAX, which was completely logical, but for some reason it always returned an error. Must have been a typo, because of course, this works. :-) Thx!